# android activity restarts from history task

Tags: android, android-activity, restart, oncreate

The problem is as follows:

Activity A (the main activity) calls activity B. If I press the home button and do some other stuff for a while, later if I want to resume from the history stack, A and B will both be restarted.

But I prefer them to just finish if they will be restarted due to low memory. Activity B is not suppose to be restarted on it's own, it's suppose to be dependable on activity A.

Comment: You Can call the activity A on restart of Activity B

Comment: How do I detect if it's a restart due to the android phone? Because oncreate is also called normally.

Comment: If you have that much coupling between the two activities, you might consider combining them into one activity and using Fragments instead.